# move custome list from 2007 to 2013

Tags: 2013, 2007, content-migration

Is there a proper process for moving a custome list from 2007 to 2013

I tried the save it as a template with content and import it but that didn't work

Can I spin up a temporary instance of 2010? then export from 2010 to 2013?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up

changing the file to .cab extracting the files and changing the version feild from 3 to 4 then repacking the cab and changing the extension back

it imported just fine

Comment: This approach is unsupported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Road map from 2007 to 2013 is, migrate to 2010 and from there to 2013.
but if it's a small list/only list, i would suggest to use 3rd party tools for migration i.e quest, metalogix, sharegate etc.

if it is very small list then you can use the free version of 3rd party tools and migrate.

Comment: what qualifies as small medium large, most are under 500 rows with about 30 - 40 columns tops